# MFMessageComposeViewController send in-app text message get phone number

Tags: ios, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

I'm using MFMessageComposeViewController to send in-app text message,it there any way to get
the number that send to? Private API is OK. Thank you in advance!

Comment: this has been asked in one form or the other in thousand variations ^^ there is no 'legal/appstore-safe' way and I don't think you can get this on stock phones -- on a jailbroken phone ANYTHING is possible

Comment: @Daij-Djan Oh,I see. Thank you and I will never ask such stupid question.

Comment: ;) cool :D I didn't want to sound too annoyed. I didn't have my coffee yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no methods for getting information back from MFMessageComposeViewController.  I think its because of privacy concerns.  I don't think I'd like anyone seeing any messages I sent without my knowledge.

Comment: Thank you. I will close this question.